# Can I access the Android SDK manager gui with IntelliJ?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea, android-sdk-tools

I just set up the android sdk with home-brew on my MacBook Pro. The android sdk is stored in usr/local/share/android-sdk . Because I also do Java development, I want to just use IntelliJ instead of downloading Android Studio also. According to [this](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/update.html), only Android Studio comes with the sdk manager gui; for other IDEs, I have to use the command-line tools. However, I figured Android Studio is a fork of IntelliJ so IntelliJ should also have the gui. I tried clicking "SDK Manager" in Intellij (Tools > Android > SDK Manager) but nothing happened.

Is anyone able to access the sdk gui with just IntelliJ? Can you please advise me on how to do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The new Android SDKs aren't bundling the SDK manager application anymore (which is what Intellij 2017.1.X and earlier attempt to launch when you go to manage the SDK). The GUI to manage the SDK is now built into the IDE via the Android Plugin (which Google writes). Intellij I am told will be getting this in the 2017.2 release. That should be in EAP now but I have not tried it.

Comment: Thank you for the information! I've been looking for hours and haven't found anything.

Comment: Happy to help. I only found out the answer because of another bug that I couldn't duplicate in Android Studio because of this difference. JetBrains support explained that to me. Please accept this answer if it did what you needed. :)

Comment: I got fed up with this myself and am using the 2017.2 EAP now. I can confirm it works there.